# How to determine the exact value of the constant in Poincaré's inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

I am reading a paper about Navier-Stokes Equations, in which the author gives the  inequality bellow
$$\|u\|_{L^2(O_R)}\le CR^{\frac{1}{2}}\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(O_R)}$$
where $u$ is a $3D$ vector field, $O_R=(B_R(0)-B_{R-1}(0))\times(0,1)\subset\mathbb{R}^3, R>0$, $C>0$ is a constant which is independent of $R$  .
I have check all kinds of Poincaré's inequalities, and I cant find one with exact value of the constant, whether additional conditions are required?
Or, under what circumstances can this constant be determined

Comment: What are the assumptions on $u$? This isn’t true in general (take $u$ constant) The assumptions are also important for determining the optimal constant

Comment: Also, are you aware that in the case $u$ is a scalar the optimal constant is one of the first eigenvalue of the domain. This doesn’t answer your question, but it might help refine your search

Comment: @JackT Conditions that may be useful are bellow: $div u=0$  and  $u=0$ when $x_3=0 $or $x_3=1$

Comment: If you write out the optimization problem to maximize $C$, you end up with a Rayleigh quotient for which the solution is the smallest eigenvalue of the Laplacian over your domain and function space. Obviously this can't be determined analytically in general